# iOS Swift: Array index out of range when accessing last property

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, ios8, xcode6.1

I'm running into an strange error. I'm appending an item to an array, and then accessing that item through the .last property, but I randomly get an "fatal error: Array index out of range".

Here is my code (which is inside a for loop):

```
var thisLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
currentMarkers.append(GMSMarker(position: thisLocation))

var calle = obj["calle"] as String
var numero = obj["numero"] as String
var colonia = obj["colonia"] as String
var direccion = "\(calle) \(numero), \(colonia)"
var horarioSemanal = obj["horario_lv"] as String
var horarioSabatino = obj["horario_s"] as String
var nombre = obj["sucursal"] as String

currentMarkers.last?.icon = UIImage(named: tipo.lowercaseString)
currentMarkers.last?.title = "\(tipo) - \(nombre)"
currentMarkers.last?.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
currentMarkers.last?.snippet = direccion
```

The error randomly shows in one of the last four lines.
I have also tried accessing it by:

```
currentMarkers[currentMarkers.count-1].snippet = direccion
```

with no luck.

This code is part of a function called fetchSucursales() which I call in the background like this:

```
let qualityOfServiceClass = Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.value)
let inverseQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
dispatch_async(inverseQueue, {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.labelStatus.text = "Obteniendo marcadores..."
        self.activityIndicatorUpdateMarkers.startAnimating()
    })

    self.fetchSucursales()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.labelStatus.text = "\(self.currentMarkers.count) marcadores encontrados."
        self.activityIndicatorUpdateMarkers.stopAnimating()
    })

})
```

If I run it in the main queue everything works fine everytime:

```
    labelStatus.text = "Obteniendo marcadores..."
    activityIndicatorUpdateMarkers.startAnimating()
    fetchNearbyPlaces()
    labelStatus.text = "\(currentMarkers.count) marcadores encontrados."
    activityIndicatorUpdateMarkers.stopAnimating()
```

It's just that my app freezes while fetching the markers if I do it like this.

The fact of it being randomly and at different lines (and after a different number of loops each time) makes me think it has something to do with it running in the background.

I'm using Xcode 6.1 (6A1052d).

Hope you can help me and many thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Implementing Nate's answer, now the error has moved to another lines, here is the start of my function:

```
func fetchSucursales() {

mapView.clear()
currentMarkers.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let enumerator:NSDirectoryEnumerator = fileManager.enumeratorAtPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath)!
while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? String {
    if element.hasSuffix("json") {

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(element.stringByDeletingPathExtension, ofType: element.pathExtension)
        let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe , error: nil)
        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        var sucursales : NSArray = jsonResult["markers"] as NSArray

        sucursalLoop: for sucursal in sucursales {
            let obj = sucursal as NSDictionary

            var tipo = obj["tipo"] as String
            var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = obj["latitud"]!.doubleValue
            var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = obj["longitud"]!.doubleValue
            if contains(searchedTypes, tipo.lowercaseString) {
                //if latitude < mapRadius["norte"] && latitude > mapRadius["sur"] && longitude > mapRadius["este"] && longitude < mapRadius["oeste"] {

                for var index:Int = 0; index < currentMarkers.count; ++index {
                    if latitude == currentMarkers[index].position.latitude && longitude == currentMarkers[index].position.longitude {
                        if tipo.lowercaseString == "cajero" {
                            continue sucursalLoop
                        }else {

                            if currentMarkers[index].title.rangeOfString("cajero") != nil {
                                currentMarkers.removeAtIndex(index)
                            }
                            //append
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Append
                var thisLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
                let newMarker = GMSMarker(position: thisLocation)
                var calle = obj["calle"] as String
                //Rest of code posted before
```

Now the error shows in the if latitude == currentMarkers[index].position.latitude && longitude == currentMarkers[index].position.longitude { line or in the if currentMarkers[index].title.rangeOfString("cajero") != nil { line.

I've added a println("(currentMakers.count)") just after the start of the for loop and I'm seeing it kind of prints garbage. It prints a lot of 1, then 2, then 3, till 8, and then:

```
8
8
8
8
8
10
10
10
10
1100

1100

1100

1100

1100

1100

10
11
11
11
11
```

At the moment of the error, index was 2 and currentMakers.count was 30.

Answer (score 0):

You could pretty easily refactor that code to not need to modify the `GMSMarker` instance while it's in the array - that should eliminate whatever threading issue you're seeing:

```
var thisLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: thisLocation)

var calle = obj["calle"] as String
var numero = obj["numero"] as String
var colonia = obj["colonia"] as String
var direccion = "\(calle) \(numero), \(colonia)"
var horarioSemanal = obj["horario_lv"] as String
var horarioSabatino = obj["horario_s"] as String
var nombre = obj["sucursal"] as String

marker.icon = UIImage(named: tipo.lowercaseString)
marker.title = "\(tipo) - \(nombre)"
marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
marker.snippet = dirección
currentMarkers.append(marker)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've implemented it but now the error went to another set of lines.  I'm not sure how to paste code in a responde so let me edit my question.